# Learning DrRacket, Why will this not return false?

Tags: scheme, racket

I have just started learning DrRacket today and I am trying to write a simple function to return true if a number is divisible by 3 and false if it is not. I wrote this:

```
(define (DivByThree real)
  (cond
    (zero? (remainder real 3) #t)
    (else #f)
  )
)
```

However, it returns #t no matter what the input is. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You only need parenthesis around "zero? (remainder real 3)" to get proper cond statement.

Answer (score 2):

There's an implicit `begin` after each condition in `cond`, and since you left out a pair of parentheses your code is equivalent to

```
(define (DivByThree real)
  (cond
    (zero? (begin (remainder real 3) #t))
    (else #f)))
```

Since your first condition is `zero?` which is "truthy" (it's not `#f`), and the value for that condition is the value of the *sequence* `(remainder real 3) #t)`, the value is always `#t`.

This would be correct:

```
(define (DivByThree real)
  (cond
    ((zero? (remainder real 3)) #t))
    (else #f)))
```

but the patterns

```
(cond ((p #t)
       (else #f)))
```

and

```
(if p #t #f)
```

are unnecessary and can both be replaced with just `p`.

Since Scheme programmers usually don't use CamelCase and end predicates with a question mark, a more idiomatic definition would be

```
(define (div-by-three? integer) 
    (zero? (remainder integer 3)))
```

Note that using the name "real" for a parameter that must be an integer is very misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Code like:

```
if some_condition
    return true
else
    return false
```

...doesn't usually make much sense. Your `some_condition` is already producing the correct result, so you might as well just return that:

```
return some_condition
```

In your case (divisible by three, Scheme syntax), that comes down to something like this:

```
(define (DivByThree? num) (zero? (remainder num 3)))
```

As an aside, note that you're defining a predicate, so you probably want a `?` on the end of the name (so somebody doesn't assume it's going to return its input divided by three).

Answer (score 1):

Note that each clause in the `cond` expression is of the form
`[question answer]`. In your example you had some misplaced parentheses.

Try this:

```
(define (DivByThree real)
  (cond
    [(zero? (remainder real 3)) #t]
    [else #f]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need parenthesis around "zero? (remainder real 3)" to get proper cond statement. But #t and #f are not needed as detailed in other answers. Moreover, if only 2 conditions are there, one can use "if" statement:

```
(define (DivByThree real)
  (zero? (remainder real 3)))

(define (DivByThree2 real)
  (cond 
    ((zero? (remainder real 3))
     (println "Yes"))
    (else (println "No"))))        ; "else" can be omitted here.

(define (DivByThree3 real)
  (if (zero? (remainder real 3))
      (println "Yes")
      (println "No")))
```